# Node.JS WebSocket client memory leaks

Tags: node.js, websocket, memory-leaks, ws

I need to hold websocket connection inside the Node.JS server. If this websocket connection errored or closed, I'm making a new one. But there probably is the problem: It causes memory leak.

As I know, you can't delete an object. So I need to somehow free memory from old WebSocket's.

Code of the websocket client usage and reconnection attempt on the events onclose onerror:

```
const connectSocket = () => {
    const someSocket = new WebSocket('wss://some.socket');
    someSocket.onopen = () => {
        ...
    };
    someSocket.onclose = () => {
        setTimeout(connectSocket, 5000);
    };
    someSocket.onerror = () => {
        setTimeout(connectSocket, 5000);
    };
    someSocket.onmessage = async (msg) => {
        ...
    };
};
```

After some reconnection attempts, memory don't clear and app crashes, because out of memory happened.

Would it work if I gonna clear events? `delete someSocket.onopen; delete someSocket.onclose //...etc`